# Copy single branch from git repo and make it independent

Tags: git, git-branch, git-clone, git-mirror

I have a git repo lets say "MyRepo", with following structure, branch1, branch2, tags, etc. 
I want to create a new git repo, "EasyStart" that has the code and history of just branch2 and I don’t want anything else like branch1, tags etc from MyRepo. And I don’t want any other links or connectivity with MyRepo. So once the EasyStart repo is setup it only has history and code of branch1 and hence forth any updates/changes done on EasyStart will not reflect in MyRepo and vice versa. How do I achieve this?

Comment: If you don't care about the history at all, you can git clone to a directory, check out the branch you want, then copy everything except `.git` into a new directory and run `git init` there. stage and commit everything into first commit on master, and push to your new repo's remote.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. We do care about the history, we want to have the history from that branch.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using a temporary repo for clean up.
The steps would be:

1. clone the original repository

```
git clone <old repo>
```

2. push it to a new temporary repository

```
git remote set-url origin <temp repo>
git remote -v
git push origin
```

3. delete all branches that you want (local and remote)

```
git fetch
git push origin --delete branch1
git branch -D branch1
```

4. delete all tags (local and remote)

```
git fetch
git push origin --delete $(git tag -l)
git tag -d $(git tag -l)
```

5. remove the remote and add your new (final) remote and push to it. This should give you a clean start.

```
git remote set-url origin <temp repo>
git remote -v
git push origin
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response. Would this keep the current existing repo as it is including branch2 of the current repo? 
I'm always scared of removing remote etc. So when I remove the remote it doesn't affect the original repo? 
Sorry for too many questions.

Comment: That is why you change the remote so that you don't touch the original remote ;) you can even backup the old remote so you can go back to it at any time. Just pay attention to the output of "git remote -v" so that you don't push to the wrong repo